# Regex expression not returning the correct term

Tags: c#, regex

Could some please tell me what is up with the my regex expression:

```
expression = (?<=current run date :)([^\.]*?)
searchString = date : 2012-05-26 03:00:00.000 to current run date : 2012-05-26 04:00:00.000
```

Expression is currently my regex search term. I keep getting a correct match but it does not return what i want, it returns "".

Below is value, this is what I am looking the regex expression to return.

```
value = 2012-05-26 04:00:00.000
```

So the last date in the string. I using c# .net 4.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your question is at the very end:

`*?`

Normally the `*` means "give me 0 or more characters that match, and give me as many as possible." The "as much as possible" is called "greedy matching". That `?` symbol is a modifier that switches from greedy matching to non-greedy matching, so effectively it becomes "give me 0 or more characters that match, and give me as FEW as possible.". In this case, the fewest number is 0.

So the fix is to remove that `?` character from your expression:

`(?<=current run date :)([^\.]*)`

**Edit:** It's also worth noting that you're using a look-ahead here but you don't need to. Look-aheads are expensive, so you shouldn't use them unless you need to. You can change your regex to this:

`current run date :([^\.]*)`

You will still get the same result, but the engine should be able to return your results faster (less overhead).

Answer (score 1):

The `?` makes the zero-or-more quantifier `*` match in a lazy or non-greedy way. In other words, it'll try to match as few as possible. In this case, it matches an empty string since that is obviously the fewest amount possible. So first of all, you'll need to get rid of that `?`.

Next up, your character sequence `[^\.]` tells the parser that it should match any character except periods `.`, but your expected result includes the milliseconds part `.000` which clearly contains a period. That part would not be matched by the character sequence, so instead you'd get something like `2012-05-26 04:00:00`.

You'll probably want to be more specific with your pattern. If you *know* that you'll get a date in this format, something like this should work:

```
expression = current run date :\s+(\d{4}\-\d{2}\-\d{2}\s\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}\.\d{3})
```

or you could be less strict and match the two next words

```
expression = current run date :\s+(\S+\s\S+)
```

Note: `\d` is a decimal character `[0-9]`, `\s` is a space character such as a space, a tab, a new line, `\S` is anything but a space character.

Comment: Good catch on the decimal part. I was so busy correcting his lazy operator that I didn't even notice that the core logic of his regex is broken.

Answer (score 0):

To return what you want, you have to grab the value from the first capture group `$1` but you will have to remove the `?` char.

The logic sais it will work with that non greedy operator, but I can't explain why it doesn't.

If you change the `*` multiplier to `+` you will see that it returns the first space between the numbers and the `:` char.